# Haskell - putStr vs putStrLn and instruction order

Tags: haskell, io, output

Let's say we have a short haskell programm:

```
main = do putStr "2 + 2 = "
          x <- readLn
          if x == 4
             then putStrLn "Correct"
             else putStrLn "Wrong"
```

What output does it produce?

> **4**
>
> 2 + 2 = Correct

Now let's have another:

```
main = do putStrLn "2 + 2 = "
          x <- readLn
          if x == 4
             then putStrLn "Correct"
             else putStrLn "Wrong"
```

*That* produces

> 2 + 2 =
>
> **4**
>
> Correct

Where the bold 4 is user-inputted.

Could anybody familiar with Haskell explain to me why that is?
And how do I get the desired result, which is

> 2 + 2 = **4**
>
> Correct

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Line buffering. The output buffer is not "flushed" until a complete line of text is written.

Two solutions:

1. Manually flush the buffer. (`putStr` followed by `hFlush stdout`.)
2. Turn off buffering. (`hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`.)